# PHP: Modifying plugin outputting video to text to make it fullscreen

Tags: javascript, php, css, wordpress

I'm modifying a PHP Wordpress plugin (Ebor template builder, built on aqua page builder).

- One of the module outputs a text box, another one outputs a background video.
- When using the background video, the module uses JS to read the window size and resizes the video to cover it completely. It seems to be doing by appending it the "fullheight" CSS class.
- I'm not using the background video functionality so I'm trying to modify that plugin to make output a textbox that resizes to screen size (instead of the video).
- Appreciate any input...I tried to make it work but I don't know much PHP :(

This is the PHP for the text functionality :

```
    //set and create block
    function __construct() {
        $block_options = array(
            'name' => 'Text',
            'size' => 'span6',
            'block_icon' => '<i class="fa fa-font"></i>',
            'block_description' => 'Use to add Text,<br />HTML or shortcodes.'
        );

        //create the block
        parent::__construct('aq_ebor_text_block', $block_options);
    }

    function form($instance) {

        $defaults = array(
            'text' => '',
            'wpautop' => 0,
            'code_display' => 0,
            'textcenter' => 0
        );

        $instance = wp_parse_args($instance, $defaults);
        extract($instance);
    ?>

        <p class="description">
            <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('title') ?>">
                Title (optional)
                <?php echo aq_field_input('title', $block_id, $title, $size = 'full') ?>
            </label>
        </p>

        <p class="description">
            <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('text') ?>">
                Content
                <?php echo aq_field_textarea('text', $block_id, $text, $size = 'full', true) ?>
            </label>
        </p>

        <p class="description">
            <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('wpautop') ?>">
                Disable Auto Paragraphs? <code>wpautop</code><br/>
                <?php echo aq_field_checkbox('wpautop', $block_id, $wpautop) ?>
            </label>
        </p>

        <p class="description">
            <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('textcenter') ?>">
                Center Text?
                <?php echo aq_field_checkbox('textcenter', $block_id, $textcenter) ?>
            </label>
        </p>

    <?php
    }// end form

    function block($instance) {
        extract($instance);

            if( !(isset( $textcenter )) )
                $textcenter = 0;

            if( $textcenter == 1 )
                echo '<div class="text-center">';

            if($title)
                echo '<h3 class="sub-heading">' . $title . '</h3>';

            if($wpautop){
                echo do_shortcode(htmlspecialchars_decode($text));
            } else {
                echo wpautop(do_shortcode(htmlspecialchars_decode($text)));
            }

            if( $textcenter == 1 )
                echo '</div>';

    }//end block

}//end class
```

This is the PHP for the background-video functionality (as you can see, it uses the "fullheight" class):

```
<?php

class AQ_Background_Video_Block extends AQ_Block {

    //set and create block
    function __construct() {
        $block_options = array(
            'name' => 'Background Video',
            'size' => 'span12',
            'block_icon' => '<i class="icon-picons-font"></i>',
            'block_description' => 'Use to add Text<br />HTML or shortcodes.'
        );

        //create the block
        parent::__construct('aq_background_video_block', $block_options);
    }//end construct

    function form($instance) {

        /**
         * Get all revsliders and load into an array.
         */
        global $wpdb;
        $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'revslider_sliders';
        $sliders = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT id, title, alias FROM $table_name" );
        $amount = count($sliders);
        $slider_choices = array('none' => 'None');
        if( is_array($sliders) ){
            for( $i = 0; $i < $amount; $i++ ){
                $slider_choices[$sliders[$i]->alias] = $sliders[$i]->title;
            }
        }

        /**
         * Build defaults and instance for this block.
         */
        $defaults = array(
            'text' => '',
            'slider' => 'none',
            'type' => 'vimeo',
            'image' => ''
        );
        $instance = wp_parse_args($instance, $defaults);
        extract($instance);

        $video_types = array(
            'vimeo' => 'Vimeo',
            'youtube' => 'Youtube'
        );

        /**
         * Check if we found any sliders and display a select box or a message accordingly.
         */
        if( $sliders ) :
    ?>

        <p class="description">
            <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('slider') ?>">
                Choose Revolution Slider to Display over the top of this video.<br/>
                <?php echo aq_field_select('slider', $block_id, $slider_choices, $slider) ?>
            </label>
        </p>

    <?php else : ?>

        <p class="description">Please Add Some Revolution Sliders if you wish to overlay content to this video.</p>

    <?php endif; ?>

        <p class="description">
            <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('type') ?>">
                Video Source
                <?php echo aq_field_select('type', $block_id, $video_types, $type) ?>
            </label>
        </p>

        <p class="description">
            <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('title') ?>">
                Video ID <code>e.g: 81676731 (Vimeo) or http://youtu.be/BsekcY04xvQ (Youtube)</code>
                <?php echo aq_field_input('title', $block_id, $title, $size = 'full') ?>
            </label>
        </p>

        <p class="description">
            <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('image') ?>">
                Fallback Static Image <code>Mobile devices do not allow background video from a device level, choose a static background image instead.</code>
                <?php echo aq_field_upload('image', $block_id, $image, $media_type = 'image') ?>
            </label>
        </p>

    <?php   
    }// end form

    function block($instance) {
        extract($instance);

        if( $type == 'vimeo' ) :
            wp_enqueue_script( 'ebor-vimeo', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/okvideo.js', array('jquery'), false, true  );
    ?>

            <div class="intro-bg fullheight">
                <div class="valign">

                    <?php 
                        if(!( 'none' == $slider ))
                            echo do_shortcode( '[rev_slider '. $slider .']' ); 
                    ?>

                </div>
            </div>

            <script type="text/javascript">
                jQuery(document).ready(function(){
                    if( !device.tablet() && !device.mobile() ) {
                        jQuery.okvideo({ 
                            source: '<?php echo $title; ?>',
                            autoplay:true,
                            loop: true,
                            highdef:true,
                            hd:true, 
                            adproof: true,
                            volume:0
                        });     
                    } else {
                        jQuery('body').addClass('poster-img');
                    }   
                });
            </script>

            <style type="text/css">
                .poster-img{
                    background-image: url(<?php echo $image; ?>) !important;
                    background-repeat: no-repeat !important;
                    background-position: center center !important;
                    background-size: cover !important;
                }
            </style>

    <?php       
        elseif( $type == 'youtube' ) :
            wp_enqueue_script( 'ebor-youtube', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/youtube.js', array('jquery'), false, true  );
    ?>

            <div class="intro-bg fullheight">
                <div class="valign">

                    <?php echo do_shortcode( '[rev_slider '. $slider .']' ); ?>

                    <a id="bgndVideo" class="player mb_YTVPlayer" data-property="{videoURL:'<?php echo $title; ?>',containment:'body',autoPlay:true, mute:true, startAt:0, opacity:1}" title="" style="display: none;"></a>

                </div>
            </div>

            <script type="text/javascript">
                jQuery(document).ready(function(){
                    if( !device.tablet() && !device.mobile() ) {        
                        jQuery(function(){
                          jQuery(".player").mb_YTPlayer();
                        });         
                    } else {
                        jQuery('body').addClass('poster-img');
                    }   
                });
            </script>

            <style type="text/css">
                .poster-img{
                    background-image: url(<?php echo $image; ?>) !important;
                    background-repeat: no-repeat !important;
                    background-position: center center !important;
                    background-size: cover !important;
                }
            </style>

    <?php
        endif;
    }//end block

}//end class
```

Comment: You're focusing on the wrong thing. At least from your code...`.fullheight` isn't actually being used for anything. I think it would be more helpful to limit your code to the portions you've modified yourself.

Comment: it's calling the script from another file:

 `//Detecting viewport dimension
     var vH = jQuery(window).height(),
       vW = jQuery(window).width(),
       cW = jQuery('.container').width(),
       fH = jQuery('.sticky-foot').height();

 jQuery('.fullheight').css('height',vH);
 jQuery('#intro, .fullheight, .text-anim-container, .pace-running').css('height',vH);
 jQuery('.foot-pad').css('margin-bottom',fH);`